# Is there a problem with having empty ViewModels that derive from a parent view model? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have designed two user controls, one for 'signals' pointing left, and one for 'signals' pointing right. Since they both have similar functionality, I designed a base view model for both of them, and created two separate view models that I could bind to.

My BaseSignalViewModel, which also inherits from a parent view model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class BaseSignalViewModel : RailwayViewModel {
        private Signal _signal;
        private LineCoordinates _segment;
        private decimal _signalPos;
        private PointCoordinates _signalCoords;

        public PointCoordinates SignalCoords {
            get => _signalCoords;
            set {
                _signalCoords = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SignalCoords");
            }
        }


    //There's more logic that isn't relevent to this question
}
```

Left and right view models for my signals, both empty.

```
public class SignalLeftViewModel : BaseSignalViewModel {
        public SignalLeftViewModel(Signal signal) : base(signal) {

        }


}

public class SignalRightViewModel : BaseSignalViewModel {
        public SignalRightViewModel(Signal signal) : base(signal) {

        }


}
```

In my XAML I'm bound within a list, and then bind to the specific view models so I know which user control to draw out.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SignalLeftViewModel}">
                            <Canvas>
                                <userControls:SignalLeftControl SignalName="{Binding Name}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SignalCoords.Y, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter},ConverterParameter=leftSignal}" Canvas.Left="{Binding SignalCoords.X, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}, ConverterParameter=leftSignal}">
                                    <userControls:SignalLeftControl.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                                    </userControls:SignalLeftControl.RenderTransform>
                                </userControls:SignalLeftControl>

                            </Canvas>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SignalRightViewModel}">
                            <Canvas>
                                <userControls:SignalRightControl SignalName="{Binding Name}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SignalCoords.Y, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter},ConverterParameter=rightSignal}" Canvas.Left="{Binding SignalCoords.X, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}, ConverterParameter=rightSignal}">
                                    <userControls:SignalRightControl.RenderTransform >
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>

                                    </userControls:SignalRightControl.RenderTransform>
                                </userControls:SignalRightControl>

                                <!--<Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" Fill="Red" Canvas.Top="{Binding SignalCoords.Y, Converter={StaticResource ScaleYCoordConverter}}" Canvas.Left="{Binding SignalCoords.X, Converter={StaticResource ScaleXCoordConverter}}" ></Ellipse>-->
                            </Canvas>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

My question is whether this is okay to do, as in to have empty view models for the sake of being able to tell which user control I need to draw? Thank you in advance and please ask if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this example of just two. If you start getting lots of empty VMs I'd probably switch to a DataTemplateSelector as Chris describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this might be to have a property on `BaseSignalViewModel` for either left or right, perhaps using an `enum` for this. You could then use a `DataTemplateSelector` class which returns the appropriate template based on that property.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll look into how to implement this now, seems like it might do the trick.

Comment: You might not even need a DataTemplateSelector. Instead, set the ContentTemplate property of a ContentControl or ContentPresenter to the desired DataTemplate by a DataTrigger in a ContentControl/Presenter Style (e.g. the ItemContainerStyle of an ItemsControl).